# Angularjs scope error

Tags: html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-model

need some help on angular i have no knowledge on, but i have a work to do ^^' . My problem is when i write into my inputs i can't get the ng-model return and get a scope error telling `$scope.newemployee is undefined`(corrected).
New problem my table 'List' stay empty like my object employee

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="employe">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
        List of employe
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width , initial-scale=0 ,shrink- to-fit=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./files/code.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="FormController as FormCtrl">
        <button ng-click="FormCtrl.setShow(2)">Add new employee</button>
        <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="ListCtrl" name="infoForm" ng-submit="addEmployee()" ng-show="FormCtrl.isShow(2)" novalidate="" id="infoForm">
            {{newemployee}}
            <h2>
                Add/Edit employee
            </h2><!-- NOM -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="texte" ng-model:"newemployee.name" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="name" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- AGE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="age" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Age</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="number" ng-model:"newemployee.age" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- NICKNAME -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nickname" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nickname</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="texte" ng-model:"newemployee.nickname" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- EMPLOYEE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="employee" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Employee</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="Yes" ng-model:"newemployee.yes" value="yes" />Yes</label> <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="No" ng-model:"newemployee.no" value="no" />No</label>
                </div>
            </div><!-- JOB -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="job" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Job</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <select ng-model:"newemployee.job" class="form-control">
                        <option>
                            Founder
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            Market chef
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            Stage
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div><!-- ANNEE -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="years" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Years</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="number" ng-model:"newemployee.years" class="form-control" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div><!-- BUTTON -->
            <div class="center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success">Validate</button> <button class="btn btn-default btn-warning" ng-click="FormCtrl.setShow(1)">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

### Here angularjs code

```
(function () {
      var app = angular.module('employe', []);

      app.controller("FormController", function () {
          this.Edit = 1;

          this.isShow = function(checkEdit){
            return this.Edit == checkEdit;
          };

          this.setShow = function(setShow){
            return this.Edit = setShow ;

          };
          console.log(this.Edit);

      });

      app.controller("ListCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.list = /*employee*/[];

        $scope.addEmployee = function(){
            $scope.list.push({
                name: $scope.newemployee.name,
                age : parseInt($scope.newemployee.age),
                nickname : $scope.newemployee.nickname,
                job : $scope.newemployee.job ,
                years : parseInt($scope.newemployee.years),
                salarie : $scope.newemployee.yes + $scope.newemployee.no                  

            });

        };


      }]);



    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably initialize the `newemployee` object inside `ListCtrl` as follows

```
app.controller("ListCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.list = /*employee*/ [];
    $scope.newemployee = {};
    $scope.addEmployee = function() {
        $scope.list.push({
            name: $scope.newemployee.name,
            age: parseInt($scope.newemployee.age),
            nickname: $scope.newemployee.nickname,
            job: $scope.newemployee.job,
            years: parseInt($scope.newemployee.years),
            salarie: $scope.newemployee.yes + $scope.newemployee.no

        });
    };
}]);
```

Sample input tag

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="name" ng-model="newemployee.name" />
```

Comment: Thanks newtt i have no longer the error message but my object is still empty :/

Comment: In your form inputs, you need to add `ng-model="newemployee.name` for the name and so on and so forth. Check edited answer for details

Comment: i''ve got them  : <input type="texte" ng-model:"newemployee.name" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="name"> on each of my input but don't know why they didn't appear . i will try to correct this

Comment: Because you're using `ng-model:"newemployee.name"` instead of `ng-model="newemployee.name"`. `ng-model` is still an attribute and you need to use `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: That's why it was red on my bracket '-' .

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the input fields to the properties you want to set. You can do this with ng-model like this:

```
<input type="texte" class="form-control" ng-required="true" name="name" ng-model="$scope.newemployee.name" />
```